# passing command line argument from main function to user define C function

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, file-pointer

i need to pass command line argument from  main function (main ) to  user defined function called (GetFile) : 
     i tried this:

**Main function:**

```
FILE *GetFile(String Extension, String RW);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
File *p
char *rootName = argv[1];
p= GetFile( ".name", "r");
if (p)
{   Do some Stuff!! }
 return 0;
}
```

**User Defined function :**

```
FILE *GetFile(String Extension, String RW)   
{
char  Fn[512];  
strcpy(Fn, rootName);
strcat(Fn, Extension);
return fopen(Fn, RW);
}
```

User defined function takes rootname file from Main function.copy it and concatenate with the extension passed by calling function

How do i pass the value of rootName  value to GetFile function outside my main function.Any help is appreciated

Comment: `FILE *GetFile(char *Extension, char *RW)` Enabling **compiler warnings** will tell you where and what is wrong. (e.g. add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile string)

Comment: thanks@David. my program works well without compilation error if i declare the value of rootName inside the function but the only problem is that i want to pass the value  of rootName from main function which the user enter as a command line argument

Comment: `rootName` is a character pointer, so it can be freely passed as a parameter and freely returned as a value from a function of type `char *`. You also have the option of passing its address, e.g. `&rootNode` (if there is a chance of the first node changing) in which case your parameter prototype would be `char **`. You can also simply add it as a parameter, e.g. `FILE *GetFile(char *filename, char *Extension, char *RW)`

Comment: Thank@David. when i try to call function GetFile from main function i got error like this :                                                                                maintame.c:128:8: error: too many arguments to function‘GetFile’
   v9 = GetFile( "&rootName" ,".name", "r");

Comment: If you are not changing `rootName`, simply pass it as `rootname` instead of `&rootname`. `error: too many arguments to function` means you did not change all of the `FILE *GetFile(char *filename, char *Extension, char *RW)` function declarations and function definitions to match the new parameter list.

Comment: i do changed all stuff (declaration and definition). what about the return type>>return fopen(filename,Extension, RW); I'am i correct

Comment: **too many arguments to function‘GetFile’ v9 = GetFile( "&rootName" ,".name", "r");** It looks like you added `rootName` where you **call it**, but not where you **declare** it. **too many arguments** means you sent 3 parameters, but based on the declaration, it was only expecting 2. Check header files for stray declarations, etc.. Post a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I will compile it here and find out.

Comment: FILE *GetFile(char *filename, char *Extension, char *RW);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments, you must be close. Here is an example with the function declaration and definition cleaned up into a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *getfile (char *rn, char *ext, char *rw);

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    FILE *p;
    char *rootname = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "somefile";

    p = getfile (rootname, ".name", "r");
    if (p)
        printf ("file open for reading!\n");
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed.\n");

    return 0;
}

FILE *getfile (char *rn, char *ext, char *rw)   
{
    char fn[512] = "";

    if (!rn || !*rn || !ext || !*ext || (*rw != 'r' && *rw != 'w')) {
        fprintf (stderr, "getfile() error: invalid parameter.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy (fn, rn);
    strcat (fn, ext);

    printf ("opening: %s, filemode: %s\n", fn, rw);

    return fopen (fn, rw);
}
```

**Example File**

```
$ touch myfile.name
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fileopenfn myfile
opening: myfile.name, filemode: r
file open for reading!
```

**Example with Unmatched Filename**

```
$ ./bin/fileopenfn
opening: somefile.name, filemode: r
error: file open failed.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Note:** While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `caMelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf)

Comment: Thanks@David the function definitely  passed the rootName, but it doesn't understand the presence  of specific file inside the directory specified by change directory(CD) in terminal window.

Comment: OK, now you lost me. When you say *"doesn't understand the presence of specific file inside the directory specified by change directory(CD) in terminal window"*. In your code, `rootname` can (1) be a **`filename alone`** which will be expected to reside in the current working directory where the executable is launched (after `.name` is added to the end); (2) a **`relative/path/to/filename`** where the code will search the path for the file; or (3) an **`/absolute/path/to/filename`** where the search begins at the `root` of the filesystem. There is no `cd` at the terminal involved??